# Gitlab - Defined stages for CI and CD are not being taken in the pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a .gitlab-ci.yml file as below:

```html
image: node:6.10.3

stages:
  - ver
  - init
  - deploy

ver:
  stage: ver
  script:
    - node --version
    - whoami
init:
  stage: init
  script:
    - npm cache clean
    - rm -rf node-modules
    - npm install

deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
  script:
    - ssh-add <(echo "$STAGING_PRIVATE_KEY" | base64 --decode)
    - git pull
    - echo "deployed to staging server"
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: MY SERVER

  only:
    - master
```

In Gitlab when I go to pipeline **I am expecting to see 3 stages which are ver, init, and deploy**. **However, It only takes the first to stages and I don't see anything for deploy.**

[image]

Comment: What branch are you building?

Comment: @Stefan, It's not the master branch.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So using the `only: master` statement in the deploy job you exclude that from being touched at all in other branches. Gitlab doesn't show it in the pipeline as it was never used for non-master branches.